# An inequality for power of positive functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $f,g,h$ be positive real vlaued functions on a finite set $\mathbb{X}$. Let $p >1$. I am wondering whether the following should be true?
$$\sum_{x\in \mathbb{X}}f(x)\left(\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}\right)^p \le \frac{\sum_{x\in \mathbb{X}}f(x)^{1-p}h(x)^p}{\sum_{x\in \mathbb{X}}f(x)^{1-p}g(x)^p}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Assume $h(x) = g(x) = 1$ and then see what your inequality says, and whether it necessarily has to be true.

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thanks :)